# How to split a column, which contains a list, into different entries in Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have below data frame

```
    A   B   C
1  A1  B1  [C1, C2]
2  A2  B2  [C3, C4]
```

I wish to transform it to

```
    A   B   C
1  A1  B1  C1
2  A1  B1  C2
3  A2  B2  C3
4  A2  B2  C4
```

What should I do? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One really simple way of doing it is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['A1', 'B1', ['C1', 'C2']],['A2', 'B2', ['C3', 'C4']]], columns = ['A', 'B', 'C'])
df1 = df.copy()
df1['C'] = df['C'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
df2 = df.copy()
df2['C'] = df['C'].apply(lambda x: x[1])
pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_values('A')
```